# Asking whether one has been in this company for a very long time?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is it right to say:

1) Have you been working with this company for a very long time?

2) Have you been with this company for a very long time?

Or are there better ways of asking?

Extra: How about "Are you with this company for a long time?" Can I use "are" in this manner?

Comment: Employees are with the company. Other businesses, contractors work with the company.

Comment: Would it be right to say " Have you been with the company for a long time?"

Comment: @SrJoven Are employees the only people 'with the company'?

Comment: @WS2 Yes. Unless you have an example otherwise?

Comment: @SrJoven In the UK large numbers of the workforce are contractors, especially in the IT industry. It avoids the rigours of employment law. Some of these 'contractors' have been 'with' the same company for years, but are not legally employees.

Comment: @WS2 Thus, *work with* vs *with* but it is a distinction that a third party would likely assume *with* to be *employed at* vs *contracted to*. *Main source of income* ... not the same as employed, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been working with this organization for quite a while?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with asking a question such as:

> Have you been working with this company for a very long time?

or

> Have you been with this company for a very long time?

is that you could get an answer such as "Yes" or "No" or "Yes, quite a while actually" that will leave you none the wiser as to how long the person has been associated with the company (in whatever capacity). A question phrased this way:

> How long have you been (working) with this company?

should yield a more informative answer.

**Update**

The answer will also depend on how the person interprets "a very long time". A very long time to one person might be 5 years whereas to another it might be 25.

Comment: This would have been better informed as a comment, as it didn't answer the question...

Comment: I beg to differ. The OP asked if there were "better ways of asking" the question and I suggested a way that "should yield a more informative answer".

Comment: The person who answered just *yes* or *no* would be ignorant of, or obtusely ignoring the conventions of discourse.

Comment: @tunny, good point - I've updated the answer to illustrate that longer answers to the OP's question could be less informative than answers to the rephrased question.